# variance estimator for a symmetrical two-sides censored normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, estimators, censoring

Suppose to draw a sample of $n$ observations from $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$, with observations outside the interval $(-c,+c)$ censored; $c$ is known and one can conveniently set $c=1$, for example.

If $m$ observations are $x_1,x_2,...,x_m$, and the other $n-m$ observations in the sample are censored, which is the ML estimator for $\sigma$ (or any other *good* estimator for it, giving priority to a closed form solution than to efficiency)?

Comment: A general answer is available at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248476/maximum-likelihood-function-for-mixed-type-distribution. It is likely it can be simplified, perhaps even into closed form, in this special case.

Comment: Also, for known $c,$ [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) gives a formula relating the variance of the censored distribution to the variance $\sigma^2$ of the original.