# How does multiplying densities together work?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, density-function

This might be a pretty simple question but I am reading about MLE and notice that we multiply densities just like we do if they were probabilities of independent events.

How does this intuitively or mathematically work?  A density, if I recall, just tells you the relative likelihood of one event over another event but it itself is not a probability.  For example, the density of 0 in Norm(0, 1) is 0.3989423, but the probability of 0 occurring is 0.

So how are we able to multiply densities together to generate a likelihood function?

I may be answering my own question here, but do we implicitly multiply the infinitesimally small bases against the densities (heights) to get a rectangle area under the curve (these are probabilities).  And since the base length is the same for all observations, we can pull it out as a constant [c = base^n].  Multiplying a function by a constant doesn't affect the location of the min/max points.  And thus we are able to drop the constant and just multiply the densities together to create our likelihood function.

I guess the key remaining assumption is events are independent.  Otherwise we need to use a joint distribution or something.

Comment: The multiplication does not derive from independent events; it expresses the multiplication of *conditional probabilities.*

Comment: How so?  For a simple binomial likelihood function, we do assume each observations is independent.

Comment: Thank you--I had thought you were referring to something slightly different.  Perhaps https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248476 answers your question?