# Can someone give me the proof why does MLE in likelihood in censored data and MLE in cox model's partial likelihood behave like normal MLE?

Tags: survival, cox-model

Edit: I should have clearly mentioned that what I mean is, under regularity conditions, MLE asymptotically ~N(true value, fisher information)

For censored one, I have a quite informal proof and would like to know the formal way to do so.

For the partial likelihood, I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "behave like normal MLE."  Are you perhaps trying to ask the question addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248476/?

Comment: @whuber I edited the post, what I mean is the property that under regularity conditions, MLE~N(true value, fisher information)