# This mixed-type family of random variables has no dominating measure, so a likelihood function can't be defined?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, measure-theory, mixed-type-data

Let
$$ X = \begin{cases}\theta & \text{with probability 1/2}\\ Z\sim N(0,1) & \text{with probability 1/2.} \end{cases}$$
Here, $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ is the parameter to be estimated. It appears this family of random variables has no dominating measure, and hence we cannot define a likelihood function.

One attempt is to write
$$P(X\in A|\theta) = \int_A f_{\theta}(x) \nu(dx)$$
where $$f_{\theta}(x) = \frac12I(x\in \{\theta\}) + \frac12\phi(x)I(x\notin \{\theta\})$$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to the dominating measure $\nu(dx)=\delta_\theta(dx)+\mathcal{L}(dx)$. Here, $I$ is the indicator function, $\phi$ is the standard normal pdf, $\delta_\theta$ is the Dirac measure at $\theta$, and $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lebesgue measure. So $f_\theta(x)$ would be the likelihood function, but the problem here is that $\nu(dx)$ depends on $\theta$, so it's not actually a dominating measure over all $\theta$.

Another attempt is to consider the answer given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/397179/207125). The author gives the same expression for $P(X\in A|\theta)$ and $f_{\theta}(x)$, but the dominating measure they use is $\nu(dx)=N(dx)+\mathcal{L}(dx)$, where $N$ is the counting measure. But this answer appears to be incorrect because
$$\int_A \frac12\phi(x)I(x\notin \{\theta\}) N(dx)=+\infty,$$
since $A\cap \{\theta\}^C$ has uncountably many points. Hence, the claim that $P(X\in A|\theta) = \int_A f_{\theta}(x) \nu(dx)$ is not true.

Is this correct? Is there some way to define the likelihood function here? It seems that it is possible to define the likelihood for mixed-type distributions if the support of the discrete part doesn't depend on the parameter, but not in this case.

Comment: This is not a very exciting inference problem: provided two observations in the sample are equal, $\theta$ is known exactly.

Comment: Yes, but I'm still interested in the theory behind defining likelihood functions. It's a minimal example to get across the difficulties I'm having.

Comment: I do not think you can define a likelihood in that case.