# How to find the maximal likelihood across different families of distributions

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Denote the observed sample by $\mathbf{x}\equiv (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.
Based on analysis of the sample data, we select $M$ candidate families of distributions to fit $\mathbf{x}$.  For family $i$, $i=1,2,\ldots,M$, we can write its likelihood function $\Lambda(\mathbf{x}, \theta_i)$, and find the values of $\theta_i$ that lead to the maximal likelihood within the family.

But we want to find the distribution of the maximal likelihood across $M$ families of distributions, which consists of discrete or/and continuous families. What can we do to achieve this?

Some tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Although statistically this question doesn't make much sense--how could one know (or assume) so little about a random variable as to be undecided about whether it has a continuous or discrete distribution? -- it is sufficiently clear to be answerable.  It would be nice to know, though, what your intended application is.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! I agree with you that people can usually decide if the data comes from continuous or discrete distribution. However, this odd question arises in my ongoing research. Surely, I can break the question into three cases: (1)  $M$ families are all continuous; (2) $M$ families are all discrete; (3) Some are continuous and some are discrete. The second one is fairly easy.

Comment: Please add that extra info as an edit to the post, then we could reopen it, I think.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248476 is a related question.  Your third situation violates assumptions of many standard maximum likelihood theorems, so don't expect much and beware of overinterpreting any results.  As far as the techniques go, this is straightforward: you maximize over each family and pick the largest among those maxima.  (@Kjetil: this question doesn't need reopening because it's not closed.)