Updating a Continuous CDF After Observing Realised Draw From Same CDF
I am trying to solve for some updated distributions, but having a little trouble conceptualizing what I am doing.
In particular, suppose I have two CDFs, say $U[0,0.8]$ and $U[0.2,1]$; call them $CDF_1$ and $CDF_2$, respectively. I draw some $x$ from one of the two CDFs, but I do not know from which one $x$ is drawn. Suppose $\mathbb{P}(CDF_1) = 0.4$ and $\mathbb{P}(CDF_2) = 0.6$. I believe this yields $E[x] = \mathbb{P}(CDF_1)\frac{0.8}{2} + \mathbb{P}(CDF_2)\frac{1.2}{2} = 0.52$.
Key question: once I observe realised $x$, I want to know the updated expectation of my next draw.
Example:

$x$ is drawn from $U[0,0.8]$ with probability $0.4$, and it is drawn from $U[0.2,1]$ with probability $0.6$.

I observe some realised $x_1$, say $x_1 = 0.4$.

Given this observation, what is the expected value of the next draw of $x$? Ie: $E[x_2 | x_1 = 0.4]$

Related question: what is the distribution of $x$ after observing $x_1$?


Standard Bayes equation does not work, since naturally $\mathbb{P}(x_1 = 0.4) = 0$ as we have a continuous distribution. Continuous Bayesian equations are better defined for ranges of $x_1$, as I understand it.
What the above set-up makes me think of are hypothesis tests, which also ask "how likely is it that the true parameter follows a given distribution, given some realised outcomes", but I am not quite sure if we can translate this type of thinking directly here (as in, could we look at tail probabilities to reach a solution?).
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Imagine your observation of $x_1$ really was just an observation of a value between $x_1-\epsilon$ and $x_1+\epsilon$ for a tiny but finite value of $\epsilon.$  What would Bayes' Theorem say in that circumstance?

Whuber, thank you very much for your help! Such a simple way to look at it, and yet it cleared it right up.

For discussion of this, with several good perspectives, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248476.
